# Python Create Directory in Windows with a ':' in the Title

Tags: python, python-3.x, mkdir, errno

I think/hope this a an easy question that I just can't find the answer to - how do I create a directory where the title contains a colon? I'm scraping data from a website with variables for section and year, and creates a directory:

```
if 'C:/Path/Data/%s' % stat:
    directory = 'C:/Path/Data/%s' % stat                
else:                
    directory = 'C:/Path/Data/%s' % stat.replace('/', ' ')
if not os.path.exists(directory):
    try:
        os.makedirs(directory)
    except OSError as e:
        if not e.errno != errno.EEXIST:
            raise
```

I have some error handling in there based on what's coming back. I had to bring in `errno` to skip the section that was erring. I want to bring in that data however - and I believe the issue is the title of the section, and thus the directory, contains a `:` in a directory like:

```
/Year: some_data/
```

I receive this error:

```
OSError: [Errno 22] Invalid argument:
Failed with OSError
```

My question is - how do I create or handle the creation of a directory with a `:` in the title? I'm just skipping over it for now.

I apologize if this is a duplicate but I couldn't find anything specifically. I'm running python 3.6 in Jupyter Notebook on Windows 10. Thank you.

Comment: Is `C:Path` supposed to be `C:/Path`?

Comment: Also, fix your indentation. Python is space-sensitive, so what you have posted is not valid Python code.

Comment: @MadPhysicist - correct, I was just masking the actual directory name, forgot the '/'. Also correct - pasting the code sent the first line over - the indentation is aligned in the actual script.

Comment: You don't. `:` marks devices in DOS, Windows, and several other systems and is a path separator in MacOS. See e.g. [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365247(v=vs.85).aspx) and [What characters are forbidden in Windows and Linux directory names?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1976007/what-characters-are-forbidden-in-windows-and-linux-directory-names)

Comment: The `if` will never be `False`: A non-empty string is always `True`.

Comment: Gotcha - so it sounds like I can't handle the special characters in the path title - rather I need to replace the character immediately after pulling it down and before creating a directory.